# Complicated sentence in the past: did vs. would do

Tags: past-tense

Consider the following:

On my way back home from  work I recalled what my boss had asked I **did** - **turned** off the lights before I **went**. Hence unfortunately I had to drive all the way back to the office.

On my way back home from  work I recalled what my boss had asked **I'd do**: **turn** off the lights before I **go**. Hence unfortunately I had to drive all the way back to the office.

Which is the correct form? Would you use a dash, colon, comma or a semicolon after the first statement? How about the conjugation of the verbs in bold?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither of your sentences are grammatically correct. Martha has offered a solution that rewords the sentence somewhat for greater clarity. However, if you want to leave the wording exactly the same and just change the tenses, you need to do the following:

> On my way back home from work I recalled what my boss had asked **me to do** - **turn** off the lights before I **go**. Hence unfortunately I had to drive all the way back to the office.

First, *asked* must be followed by *accusative + infinitive*, not by *subject + finite verb*, which is what you have. So you say "asked him to leave", "asked me to go", "asked them to talk", etc.

The text after the dash is implicitly also part of an infinitive, so there is an understood *to* that begins the whole clause. Since *to* is always followed by a plain form, that's what you need in the second clause.

Comment: Can't you say "I requested (that) she bring the paper" though? I'm specifically trying to avoid that "to".

Comment: I'm pretty sure it should be " **turn** off the lights before I **went** ". I just can't cite (or even name) the specific grammatical case being used here.

Comment: "I requested she bring the paper" is correct. This construction always takes a plain form, never a tensed form.

Comment: "I requested that you turn off the lights before you leave" --> "I had requested that you turned off the lights before you left". Am I wrong there?

Comment: @JSBangs but "I asked she bring the paper" doesn't work?

Comment: @sombe "I had requested that you turned off the lights before you left" is not grammatical. You have to say "I had requested that you turn off the lights before you left". In the formula "request that *somebody* *verb*", *verb* must be subjunctive, which means the uninflected form.

Comment: "...had asked (that) I do" is also correct. Don't forget our dear friend the subjunctive.

Comment: @sombe, "I asked she bring the paper" is incorrect, but "I asked *that* she bring the paper" is correct.

Comment: @sombe, "I asked she bring the paper" is incorrect. Grammatical would be to say "I asked that she bring the paper" or "I asked her to bring the paper".

Comment: @Martha: The boss *had asked* (past perfect) and hence I believe that the actual request after the dash would be in the present tense (i.e. at the time when he had asked).

Comment: Both "turn off the lights before I go" and "turn off the lights before I went" are grammatical. In the first phrase, the verb "go" is viewed as part of the boss's request, so it's in the present tense. In the second, the verb "go" is viewed from your current position in time, so it's past tense.

Answer (score 2):

Uh, none of the above.

> On my way home from work I recalled that the boss had 
>   asked me to turn off the lights before I left*, so 
>   unfortunately I had to drive all the way back to the office.

*You can use "went" instead of "left", but the latter sounds better to my ear. (Went where?)

"...my boss had asked I did" refers to an action you already took in the past, about which your boss was curious - i.e. he didn't ask you to do something, but asked you about something you did. Similarly, "...my boss had asked I would do" refers to your boss' curiosity about a hypothetical action you would have taken. Neither works grammatically with the rest of the sentence.

Comment: I realize your example would be more foolproof, but I need the specific context in which I gave it. I'm pretty sure one or the other is correct there...

Answer (score 1):

Neither presented option is grammatical.

The syntax of forms like “ask that somebody verb” and “ask somebody to verb” requires that *verb* be in the subjunctive.

Comment: it sounds a little off. Doesn't the subjunctive take a past form as well (like in French for instance)?

Comment: @sombe in this case, it is *mandative subjunctive*, and it always takes the present subjunctive. Past subjunctive forms are only used for other kinds of subjunctive clauses, such as irrealis (“If I were president...”)